# Call to a member function prepare() on null working with MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I don't know why I'm getting this error. I looked through some already posted answers. Not helpful.

Here is my code:

```
public static function validateLogin($postdata){
    $dba = new DatabaseAgent("mysql",DBUSER,DBPASSWD,"localhost","projectdatabase");  

    $username = $postdata['username'];
    $password = $postdata['password'];

    //Setup the query()
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = $username AND password = $password";

    //Setup the bind parameters
    $bindParams = ['username' => $postdata['username'], 'password' => $postdata['password']];

    //Pull the resultset
    $resultset = $dba->query($query, $bindParams);
    $usertype = ($resultset[0]->type);
    var_dump($resultset);

    if ($resultset){
        //Return true
        return true;
    } else {
        //Return false if the user was not logged in.
        return false;
    }
}
```

And here is the PDO code:

```
public function __construct($dbtype, $user, $pass, $host, $dbname) {
    $this->dsn = $dbtype.":host=".$host.";dbname=".$dbname;
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->pass = $pass;

    // Set options  
    $options = array(  
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,  
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION  
    ); 

    //Try to connect, if not barf
    try {  
        $this->pdo = new PDO($this->dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);  
    }  catch (PDOException $e) {
        $this->error = $e->getMessage();  
    }  
}

function query($strQuery, $bindParams) {
    try {
        $this->stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($strQuery);
        $this->stmt->execute($bindParams);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo "Error Executing Query:".$ex->getMessage();
    }

    $resultset = null;

    while ($result =  $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        $resultset[] = $result;
    }

    return $resultset;
```

Comment: `$this->pdo` is `null`.

Comment: Where do you create the object?

Comment: Have you made the PDO object and just forgotten to include it?

Answer (score 0):

you just assign the error message to a variable and do nothing else when `$pdo` throws an exception. Your code will never know whether the PDO instantiation was successfull or not.

Therefore, I assume that `$pdo` instantiation fails silently and your `$pdo` attribute is null. Replace `$this->error = $e->getMessage();` with `throw $e;` and see what happens.